# How to force a method to do something or force parameter value in phpunit?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I'm really not sure that what I need to do is even possible, but maybe I could be surprised...

For a bit of context : I'm trying to test an API that calls a method `'createAttachment'` :

```
public function createAttachment(string $type, int $id, UploadedFile $file)
    {
         // stuff
         $attachment = new Attachment();
         $attachment->setPath($uploadDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filenamePath);
         // stuff
         $this->em->persist($attachment);
         $this->em->flush();
    }
```

Currently the path that's created dynamically through `setPath()` is not appropriate for my test because it creates a file where I don't want it to be created.

So my need here is to make sure that `setPath()` will always set the value that I want to $path property, so that when $attachment is being saved, the location of the file is where I want.

A big problem here could be that `Attachment` is not passed to `createAttachment` using DI but it is instantiated inside the method, so most likely It's not even "mockable".

Below a sneak peack of the Attachment entity :

```
class Attachment {

    private ?string $path;

    public function setPath(?string $path): self
        {
            $this->path = $path;
    
            return $this;
        }
```

Comment: Have I understood correctly that you want to set $path without using setPath()?

Comment: @Bademeister The finality is to be able to force a value to the $path property of Attachment class before the object is being saved in the database. Since this property is private, I need to force setPath to set the value that I want to specify to $path property.

Comment: Maybe I still don't get it, I understand that you want to set the value of a property that is private. I would use Reflections: https://www.yellowduck.be/posts/test-private-and-protected-properties-using-phpunit

Comment: My goal is not to access this property directly but to force setPath($value) to set the value that I specify. I test a method that calls setPath() in its instructions, so I. need to mock setPath so the value it sets to $path property is a value that I force, and not a value that depends on the script. Is that clearer ? @Bademeister

Comment: An object that is initialised for mocking has more or less functionless methods. I am also not aware that private members are initialised. I'm not sure about protected members, but it doesn't make sense. Only with the mock framework do you build up the behaviour of the public members. Therefore, I don't think I understand what you want to do. Setting $path with setPath() will do nothing, because $path does not exist. There is actually no reason to mock private members. There is still partial mocking, but I don't know if that can help with your requirements.

Comment: @Bademeister I modified my post to give more context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254327/discussion-between-bademeister-and-naspy971).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of our chat. I think this is what reflectoring could look like. Above all, you can test the UploadPathBuilder separately. And for UploadedFile you create a Mock.

```php
interface UploadPathBulderInterface
{
    public function getPath(): string;
}


class UploadPathBuilder implements UploadPathBulderInterface
{
    private UploadedFile $file;

    /**
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function __construct(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function getPath(): string
    {
        // stuff
        return $uploadDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filenamePath;
    }
}


class TestUploadPathBuilder implements UploadPathBulderInterface
{
    public function getPath(): string {
        return "/my/path/for/testing";
    }
}

class FooBar 
{
    public function createAttachment(string $type, int $id, UploadPathBulderInterface $pathBulder)
    {
        // stuff
        $attachment = new Attachment();
        $attachment->setPath($pathBulder->getPath());
        // stuff
        $this->em->persist($attachment);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

**Implementation Applikation**

```php
$fooBar = new FooBar();
$fooBar->createAttachment(
    "string",
    1234,
    new UploadPathBuilder($file);
);
```

**Implementation Test**

```php
$fooBar = new FooBar();
$fooBar->createAttachment(
    "string",
    1234,
    new TestUploadPathBuilder();
);
```